# Unlayer email editor - How to disable the ability to exit view mode

Tags: javascript, angular

I can open preview with  `unlayer.showPreview("desktop")`. But user leaves preview mode when click on overlay. How can I prevent user from closing preview ? Custom css is premium feature so i can't increase body area to hide overlay

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding absolute block with 4 divs that acts like border and blocks clicks on overlay and "close" button. Works like a charm). Pointer-events on absolute block are none to prevent it from blocking whole area. Pointer events on "border divs" are reenabled to block overlay from trigging and closing preview mode

```css
.unclickable-box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.unclickable-box-border{
  pointer-events: all;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
}
.unclickable-box-border__top{
  width: 100%;
  height: $unclickable-box-border-size;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.unclickable-box-border__bottom{
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: $unclickable-box-border-size;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.unclickable-box-border__left {
  width: $unclickable-box-border-size;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.unclickable-box-border__right {
  right: -10px;
  width: $unclickable-box-border-size * 2;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```